# Numbering array by month and reset to 1 on new month and year

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, grouping, date-range

I have data in an array which has a structure like this

```
[
    {createdAt: "2022-03-12T13:15:41.844+00:00", "name": 'adipiscing'},
    {createdAt: "2022-03-04T11:56:27.545+00:00", "name": 'consectetur'},
    {createdAt: "2021-01-15T09:12:25.418+00:00", "name": 'amet'},
    {createdAt: "2021-01-09T09:12:25.418+00:00", "name": 'sit'},
    {createdAt: "2021-01-02T08:52:55.418+00:00", "name": 'dolor'},
    {createdAt: "2021-12-15T09:12:25.418+00:00", "name": 'ipsum'},
    {createdAt: "2021-12-11T08:52:55.418+00:00", "name": 'lorem'},
]
```

The data above is sorted in desc by createdAt.

Currently for numbering I use the index data as usual,
I want to change the numbering based on the createdAt column but at every change of month or entry in a new month or year, the number resets to 1 again

Can anyone help me, I'm very grateful.

Comment: Perhaps you should show your attempt - or at the very least show how you're iterating that array. Set up a basic snippet and you'll probably get more help

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective:

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method to get either YYYY-MM (if full=false) or YYYY-MM-DD (otherwise)
const getDtYMD = (dt, full = false) => (
  full ? dt.createdAt.split('T')[0] : dt.slice(0, 7)
);
// transform the arr to add a group-id (idGroup)
const sortAndGroup = arr => (
  Object.values( // get the values of the result object
    [...arr.map(x => ({...x}))].sort( // first sort the input-array reverse-chronological order (latest date at 0)
      (a, b) => (getDtYMD(a, true) > getDtYMD(b, true) ? 1 : -1)
    ).reduce( // use .reduce to iterate over the sorted array
      (acc, {createdAt : c, name}) => ({
        ...acc, // safe-keep existing accumulator object
        [getDtYMD(c)]: ([
          ...(acc[getDtYMD(c)] || []),
          { // append new object to value array for key YYYY-MM
            idGroup: (acc[getDtYMD(c)]?.length || 0) + 1,
            createdAt: c, // update 'idGroup' based on existing value-array's length
            name
          }
        ])
      }),
      {}
    )
  ).flat().sort(
    (a, b) => (
      getDtYMD(a, true) > getDtYMD(b, true)
      ? -1
      : getDtYMD(a, true) < getDtYMD(b, true)
        ? 1
        : a.idGroup > b.idGroup ? -1 : 1
    )
  )
);


const unsortedRawDataArray = [
    {'createdAt': "2022-03-12T13:15:41.844+00:00", "name": '1 adipiscing'},
    {'createdAt': "2022-03-04T11:56:27.545+00:00", "name": '1 consectetur'},
    {'createdAt': "2022-03-04T11:56:27.545+00:00", "name": '2 consectetur'},
    {'createdAt': "2022-03-04T11:56:27.545+00:00", "name": '3 consectetur'},
    {'createdAt': "2021-01-15T09:12:25.418+00:00", "name": '1 amet'},
    {'createdAt': "2021-01-09T09:12:25.418+00:00", "name": '1 sit'},
    {'createdAt': "2021-01-09T09:12:25.418+00:00", "name": '2 sit'},
    {'createdAt': "2021-01-09T09:12:25.418+00:00", "name": '3 sit'},
    {'createdAt': "2021-01-02T08:52:55.418+00:00", "name": '1 dolor'},
    {'createdAt': "2021-01-02T08:52:55.418+00:00", "name": '2 dolor'},
    {'createdAt': "2021-12-15T09:12:25.418+00:00", "name": '1 ipsum'},
    {'createdAt': "2021-12-11T08:52:55.418+00:00", "name": '1 lorem'},
];

console.log('sorted-grouped: ', sortAndGroup(unsortedRawDataArray));
console.log('original-array: ', unsortedRawDataArray);
```

**Explanation**

Description of the steps are added to the above code snippet as inline comments.

**EDIT**

> when there is data that has the same date/day the order returns to 1
> again,

The data in the array has been updated to have multiple data with same date & the `idGroup` is shown to not reset.

> besides is there a way to reverse the number without changing the
> index, for example from 1-3 to 3-1.

This has been done in the updated snippet. After the `.flat()` we add another `.sort()` which considers not just the date, but also the `idGroup` in order to make the numbers go from 3-1 (reverse).

**EDIT 2**

> why after calling the sortAndGroup() function the data from
> unsortedRawDataArray also changes

This has been fixed. The incoming `arr` (array) was directly mutated via `.sort`, and the latest version of the answer copies the `arr` array.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help, but when there is data that has the same date/day the order returns to 1 again, besides is there a way to reverse the number without changing the index, for example from 1-3 to 3-1. 
i am a beginner and i am very confused about this :'

Comment: https://ibb.co/dczL9Kd

Comment: myLord @jsN00b,  i want to ask, why after calling the sortAndGroup() function the data from unsortedRawDataArray also changes, I have tried to put rawdata into state, but the data keeps changing

Comment: :-) If you'd not like to have the original array changed, please make call like this: `sortAndGroup([...unsortedRawDataArray.map(x => ({...x}))]);` - it's a simple fix. Or, you can change the function to first deep-copy the parameter array into a locally-scoped variable and then process using that. Let me know if you need the answer to be updated.

Comment: Previously I've tried to put into local variable but still the raw data changes too, I tried to use the way you suggested with sortAndGroup([...dataBooking]) and it worked.
Thanks again for your great response :)

Comment: You're welcome brother. Have also updated the answer (explained in "EDIT 2") - so you wouldn't need to use `...` spread-operator when making the call.